# How Do I Wrap Text So My Accordions Image Does Go OutSide My aAccordion

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page on my website which has many accordions on it.  My accordions also have a an image on so a user knows they can expand/collapse it.

This is done via CSS as shown below:

```
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle:after 
{
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content: "\e113";
    float: right;
}
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
    content: "\e114";
}
```

One of my accordions are set up as follows:

```
<div id="accordion" class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" href="#collapseOne" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse">How do I set up the regular investment service for my clients?</a>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Content here.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But the problem I have is that when the text gets to the end it pushes my image out of the grey box as show below

[image: Long heading pushes image out]

What I want is for it to look exactly how it does when the heading is not to long or for the image to be vertically aligned top or middle but **NOT** bottom

[image: Normal heading with image]

I am using HTML5 MVC4 with bootstrap and I would like to do this without the need for JAVA/Jquery as I was able to get the image to flick from expand to collapse just using the CSS above.

Thanks
Antony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to position the glyph absolutely and give padding right to the greybox link:

```
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle:after {
 font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';
 content:"\e113";
 position: absolute;
 right: .5em;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -10px
}
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
 content:"\e114";
}

.panel-heading .accordion-toggle {
 border: 1px solid red;
 padding-right: 2em;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for although I removed some bits from your CSS but other than that, worked like a dream. Thanks Ant